# Elvis Operator in *ngIf

Tags: angular

I know that in previous angular versions an elvis operator did not work in an *ngIf statement. However, now (Angular 6) it doesn't throw an error anymore.

Is this a valid statement?

```
<div *ngIf="testobject?.sub?.subobj">
    Hallo Test Test
</div>
```

Whereas

```
testobj = {}
```

If so when was it added?

As far as I can remember the statement had to be the following:

```
<div *ngIf="testobject.sub && testobj.sub.subobj">
    Hallo Test Test
</div>
```

Can someone please clarify that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To translate the code into plain English will be, if `testobject` is not `null`, get `sub` and if `sub` is not `null` get `subobj` and if `testobject` and `sub` and `subob`j aren't null, output `Hallo Test Test`. So yeah, the code is valid.

Answer (score 1):

More correct like this

```
<div *ngIf="testobject && testobject.sub && testobj.sub.subobj">
    Hallo Test Test
</div>
```

Says that if `testobject` is not *falsy*, then go to it's property with name `sub` - and if this is also is not *falsy*, go to the nested property `subobj` and access its data and evaluate inside `*ngIf`. If some of the conditions is *falsy*, return `false`.